# How can I estimate the volume of a solid object, knowing only it's longitudinal corss-sectional area?

Tags: volume, solid-geometry, solid-of-revolution

Let's say the shape is too complex to split it into simpler parts and solve it analytically.

I can obtain it's longitudinal cross-sectional area by loading the image into an image editor, scaling it appropriately to the point where 1px$^{2}$ = 1mm$^{2}$, then by measuring the number of pixels inside the shape, I can get the approximate area.
[Here is a simple example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kybb.png)

Since I know that this value is the result of evaluating this definite integral here:
$ A=\int_{a}^{b}r(x)dx$

And that the volume of a solid of revolution obtained by rotating the same shape around the x axis:
$V=\pi\int_{a}^{b}\left[r(x)\right]^2dx$

I'm wondering if by some method I can get from one to another?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it known that the object has rotational symmetry?

Comment: Yes, it definitely does.

Comment: The thing is, you can't really go from $A$ to $V$ in a general case because different parts of the area are "weighted" differently - an area $dA$ twice as far from the symmetry axis than the same $dA$ closer to the axis will contribute twice the volume.

Comment: I had an intuitive feeling this was the case, but I was hoping to be proven wrong. :( Thank you for confirming my suspicions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need more information. For example, consider a semicircle of radius $1$. Then the area is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the resulting volume is $\frac{4\pi}{3}$. Now consider a rectangle of height $1$ and width $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then the area is again $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but the resulting volume is now $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$.